# How to read response strings in plist?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, plist, elementtree

I am trying to parse plist to get the response string for the field "What Change bugs are fixed in this submission? "
as below but somehow it is always empty? can someone provide guidance on why it is wrong?

**plist snippet:**

```
<dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>What Change bugs are fixed in this submission? </string>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>multiline</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>releases</key>
        <array>
            <string>Yukon</string>
        </array>
        <key>response</key>
        <string>&lt;change://problem/45317899&gt; hostapd to include IOKit framework
&lt;change://problem/35143400&gt; Yukon: hostapd-33 contains references to deprecated TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED macro</string>
    </dict>
```

**CODE:-**

```
from lxml import etree as et
plistfile = '/Users/username/autosubmissionlogs/Yukon/02192019_200740/hostapd-34/hostapd-34.plist'
with open(plistfile) as raw:
    # Parse the XML input file into a tree.
    tree = et.parse(raw)
    stringUsedAsKey = tree.xpath("/plist/dict/dict/string"
            + "[./text()=\"What Change bugs are fixed in this submission?\"]")[0]
    interestingDict1 = stringUsedAsKey.getparent()
    string = interestingDict1.xpath("key[text()=\"response\"]/following-sibling::string")[0]
    print('Changes \n:'%string)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
&lt;change://problem/45317899&gt; hostapd to include IOKit framework
&lt;change://problem/35143400&gt; Yukon: hostapd-33 contains references to deprecated TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED macro
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting - I updated my question with `EXPECTED OUTPUT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is the way you are printing the result. Here's the correct way.

```
from lxml import etree as et
plistfile = '/Users/username/autosubmissionlogs/Yukon/02192019_200740/hostapd-34/hostapd-34.plist'
with open(plistfile) as raw:
    # Parse the XML input file into a tree.
    tree = et.parse(raw)
    stringUsedAsKey = tree.xpath("/plist/dict/dict/string"
            + "[./text()=\"What Change bugs are fixed in this submission?\"]")[0]
    interestingDict1 = stringUsedAsKey.getparent()
    string = interestingDict1.xpath("key[text()=\"response\"]/following-sibling::string")[0]
    print("{}{}".format('Changes \n:', string.xpath("text()")))
```

Comment: No,that did not help,you just appended `//` to key,right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plist = [your snippet above]
root = et.fromstring(plist)
resp = root.xpath('//key[text()="response"]/following-sibling::string')
for i in resp:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
<change://problem/45317899> hostapd to include IOKit framework
<change://problem/35143400> Yukon: hostapd-33 contains references to deprecated TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED macro
```